# How do I pay for the entire Reserved Instance with one upfront payment after AWS’s Free Tier

Tags: amazon-aws, amazon-ec2, pricing

My AWS's Free Tier is about to expire. How do I pay for the entire Reserved Instance with one **upfront** payment?

I noticed from that [Amazon EC2 Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/) reserved instances with the **All Upfront** option is cheaper.

Does reserved instances (like `t2.micro`) include EBS storage ([Amazon EBS Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/))? If yes, what is the size?

Comment: I agree with Ouroborus about the fact that this question should be discussed with the amazon aws billing department instead of here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not **[about a website you control](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**. This *may* be a better fit at [webapps.se]. Be sure to read their [FAQ](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help) before posting to make sure your question meets their requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are questions you should be asking the AWS billing department. Contact info is found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/).

EC2 Reserved Instances requires buying a time block on a certain instance, rather than going hour to hour with the on demand instances, with the selection of all upfront, partial upfront/partial monthly, or monthly billing. As you move towards monthly, the cost increases, but it's still cheaper than the on demand instances. You pay in advance for what you expect to use for a period of time. Otherwise the instances themselves are the same. **EC2 instances do not include EBS**, outside of the free tier. EC2 pricing (reserved and regular) is [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/).

Elastic Block Storage (EBS) is a separate product and doesn't appear to have upfront pricing. Pricing for that is over [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/).

Comment: Thx. How will `t2.micro` be charged after expiring, on-demand or monthly?

Comment: @SparkandShine The instance will switch to On Demand which is charged per instance hour, rounded up. The bill itself is due monthly.

Comment: @SparkandShine That's not to be confused the Reserved Instances monthly billing where you buy 1 year's or 3 year's worth of instance hours in advance and pay for it at a monthly rate.